# Unsetting Facebook Open Graph tags by giving them empty values?

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I'm looking into using Facebook's Open Graph but in certain circumstances I need to unset properties. For complicated reasons removing the meta elements might not be possible but changing it might be.

Is it considered valid for this:
`<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/image.jpg">`

To be reset by simply doing this:
`<meta property="og:image" content="">`

...Or is this considered invalid and bad form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the specification](http://ogp.me/#url), a URL is:

> A sequence of Unicode characters that identify an Internet resource.  All valid URLs that utilize the http:// or https:// protocols

An empty string is invalid.

**But** it won't break anything. A crawler will see the metatag, and then try to display the empty content.

Comment: That's basically what seems to happen. If you set it to an empty value they don't seem to break at all. Facebook, for example, just renders the best case it can and goes from there.